# Copy Properties Between Records

Tags: f#

Amongst several other State-related types, I have the following records types in my code:

```
type SubmittedSuggestionData = {
    SuggestionId : Guid
    SuggestionText : string
    Originator : User
    ParentCategory : Category
    SubmissionDate : DateTime
}

type ApprovedSuggestionData = {
    SuggestionId : Guid
    SuggestionText : string
    Originator : User
    ParentCategory : Category
    SubmissionDate : DateTime
    ApprovalDate : DateTime
}
```

These then feed into the following:

```
type Suggestion = 
    | SubmittedSuggestion of SubmittedSuggestionData
    | ApprovedSuggestion of ApprovedSuggestionData
```

This gives me the ability to work with a State machine style pattern to carry out specific business logic dependent upon State. (This approach was taken from: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-representing-states/)

I have a function that in it's simplest form, changes a `SubmittedSuggestion` to an `ApprovedSuggestion`:

```
let ApproveSuggestion suggestion =
    match suggestion with
    | SubmittedSuggestion suggestion -> ApprovedSuggestion {}
```

This function is incomplete at the moment as what I'm struggling to comprehend is when a Suggestion changes from Submitted to Approved, how do you copy the properties from the passed in `suggestion` into the newly created `ApprovedSuggestion` whilst also populating the new property of `ApprovalDate`?

I guess it would work if I did something like:

```
let ApproveSuggestion suggestion =
    match suggestion with
    | SubmittedSuggestion {SuggestionId = suggestionId; SuggestionText = suggestionText; Originator = originator; ParentCategory = category; SubmissionDate = submissionDate} -> 
        ApprovedSuggestion {SuggestionId = suggestionId; SuggestionText = suggestionText; Originator = originator; ParentCategory = category; SubmissionDate = submissionDate; ApprovalDate = DateTime.UtcNow}
```

but that looks pretty horrific to me.

Is there a cleaner, more succinct way of getting the same outcome? I've tried using the `with` keyword but it didn't compile.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is a large overlap between types, it is often a good idea to think about decomposition. For example, the types could look like this:

```
type SuggestionData = {
    SuggestionId : Guid
    SuggestionText : string
    Originator : User
    ParentCategory : Category
    SubmissionDate : DateTime
}

type ApprovedSuggestionData = {
    Suggestion : SuggestionData
    ApprovalDate : DateTime
}
```

Depending on the usage and differences between the types, one could also consider to have the approved type only within the discriminated union, skipping the second type altogether:

```
type Suggestion = 
    | SubmittedSuggestion of SuggestionData
    | ApprovedSuggestion of SuggestionData * approvalDate : DateTime
```

A common argument against such decomposition is that access to members of types deeper down the hierarchy becomes more verbose, e.g. `approvedSuggestionData.Suggestion.Originator`. While this is true, properties can be used to forward commonly used members of constituents if verbosity becomes annoying, and any downside should be weighed against the advantages: there is less code duplication in the types, and any operation that the more granular types offer can be made available from the composed type.

The ability to easily construct an approved suggestion from an unapproved suggestion and the approval date is one case in which this is useful. But there could be more: say, for example, there is an operation that validates the users and categories of all suggestions, approved or not. If the types holding the `Originator` and `ParentCategory` members for approved and unapproved suggestions are unrelated, the code that gets these needs to be duplicated. (Or a common interface would need to be created.)

Comment: Hmmm, I like the look of this one @Vandroiy. My states won't vary to drastically so this may well be a valid solution for me. I'll give it a shot and let you know :)

Answer (score 4):

I would change your suggestion to

```
type SubmittedSuggestionData = {
    SuggestionId : Guid
    SuggestionText : string
    Originator : User
    ParentCategory : Category
    SubmissionDate : DateTime
    ApprovalDate : DateTime option
}
```

and then approval becomes

```
let approve t = {t with AprovalDate =Some(System.DateTime.Now)}
```

Comment: Thanks @John Palmer. It has crossed my mind to do this but I'm slightly loathed to as I've used a State pattern several times in C# and the thing which has made me cringe at my previous implementations is the presence of unnecessary properties within a certain state. Ideally I'd like a clean domain model where only relevant properties are found within their respective record types. :)

Comment: That property is not really "unused", it does indicate whether the suggestion is approved or not.

Answer (score 4):

Both the suggestions offered by @Vandroiy and @JohnPalmer are good, but for completeness' sake, I'd like to offer a third perspective as well.

As far as I know, there's no language construct that will make copying of values between 'similar' types succinct. The reason for that is that these types are *different*. Their similarity is incidental, but seen from the type system, they are completely different types. If you look at them 'mathematically', they are simply types `A` and `B`.

In such cases, I'd often simply bite the bullet and add a **translation function** that translates values of one type to values of the other type:

```
let approve (suggestion : SubmittedSuggestionData) = {
    SuggestionId = suggestion.SuggestionId
    SuggestionText = suggestion.SuggestionText
    Originator = suggestion.Originator
    ParentCategory = suggestion.ParentCategory
    SubmissionDate = suggestion.SubmissionDate
    ApprovalDate = DateTime.UtcNow }
```

While it seems a little verbose, you're still keeping it DRY because such copying of values is constrained to that single function.

Furthermore, such a function can often be given a good name, which means that the function becomes part of your Domain Model.